# Does servlet context param name need to be unique?

Tags: servlets

Does the param name in the context-param(i.e servlet context parameters) need to be unique? Or can I have multiple param values for the same param name ?

Comment: Are you using multiple servlet-contexts in your project?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about [ServletContext#getInitParameter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29) (the one which you can set in web.xml), then yes, it can only have a (single) String value.

But if the interpretation of that String is up to you (such as when it is your own servlet you are configuring), you could pass in something like a comma-separated list of values.